# Bubble Sort Outer Loop and N-1

Tags: c, bubble-sort

I've read multiple posts on Bubble Sort, but still have difficulty verbalizing why my code works, particularly with respect to the outer loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < (n - 1); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < (n - i - 1); j++)
    {
        if (array[j] > array[j + 1])
        {
            int temp = array[j];
            array[j] = array[j + 1];
            array[j + 1] = temp;
         }
     }
 }
```

For any array of length n, at most n-1 pairwise comparisons are possible.  That said, if we stop at i < n-1, we never *see* the final element.  If, in the worst case, the array's elements (I'm thinking ints here) are in reverse order, we cannot assume that it is in its proper place.  So, if we never examine the final array element in the outer loop, how can this possibly work?

Comment: How do you declare your array?

Comment: The array is of arbitrary size. Let's say array[] = { 5, 1, 4, 2, 8 }, for example. In the above code, n = 5.  Thanks for looking at this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line you are accessing 1 element ahead of current position of j

```
 array[j + 1];
```

In first iteration of the loop you run j from 0 to j<(n-0-1), so last index of array which you can get is j less than n, as you accessing array[j+1]. So if you declare you array as array[n], this will get the last element for your array.

Answer (score 2):

Array indexing is done as 0 to n-1. If there are 10 elements in array, indexing will be n-1. So in first, iteration of inner loop (n-1) comparison will take place. First pass of bubble sort will bubble up the largest number to its position.

In the next iteration (n-1-1) iteration will take place and it will bubble up the second largest value to its place and so on until the whole array is sorted.

Answer (score 1):

n is typically the number of elements in your array, so if 10 elements in the array, the elements would be indexed from 0 - 9.  You would not want to access array[10] in the outer loop as this would yield a segfault for accessing out of array bounds, hence the use of "n -1" in the loop condition statement. In C, when writing and calling a function that includes iterating an array, the size of the array is also passed as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It's the < sign that's causing the confusion. You are 100% correct that n - 1 is the last element in our array, but if I stop at i < n -1, rather than i <= n-1, I don't see how I get there.

Answer (score 1):

The `n` means the "number of all the elements".  The initial number in the loops is 0, ranging from 0 to (n-1); so we will get n elements; all the elements will be travelsaled.